# Oracle, Cursor_Sharing = Force and Queries with literal comparisons forcing FTS

Tags: oracle, performance, oracle-11g-r2, query-performance

I have the following scenario:

- Oracle 11.2.0.3
- A 3rd party application, that requires cursor_sharing = TRUE
- A table (T2310) with a indexed field (C1000000161) that has no duplicated values
- Result Cache Mode = force (don't believe this is relevant in this case, but it's here to justify its appearance in the explain)

The 3rd party application is running queries like the one below (I have to use the hint here, since the `explain` won't show the FTS):

```
    SQL> select /*+ GATHER_PLAN_STATISTICS */ C1000000161 
    > from aradmin.T2310 
    > where C1000000161 = 'INC000002137945' or ('a' = 'b');
```

This kind of query ends up forcing a full table scan:

```
SQL> SELECT * FROM table(DBMS_XPLAN.DISPLAY_CURSOR(FORMAT=>'ALLSTATS LAST'));

PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SQL_ID  f3njwvkb0yf1x, child number 0
-------------------------------------
select /*+ GATHER_PLAN_STATISTICS */ C1000000161 from
aradmin.T2310 where C1000000161 = :"SYS_B_0" or (:"SYS_B_1"
= :"SYS_B_2")

Plan hash value: 1862236576

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation          | Name                       | Starts | E-Rows | A-Rows |   A-Time   | Buffers | Reads  |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT   |                            |      1 |        |      0 |00:03:00.20 |    3964K|    161K|
|   1 |  RESULT CACHE      | bkhyzz7n945syc4numpbs27y20 |      1 |        |      0 |00:03:00.20 |    3964K|    161K|
|*  2 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL| T2310                      |      1 |  44030 |      0 |00:03:00.20 |    3964K|    161K|
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   2 - filter((:SYS_B_1=:SYS_B_2 OR "T2310"."C1000000161"=:SYS_B_0))

Result Cache Information (identified by operation id):

PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
------------------------------------------------------

   1 -
```

As we can see in the `explain`, the literals are replaced by bind variables, and I believe this is what is forcing the FTS. If you remove the literal comparison, the index is used as expected.

So, my question is: is there any way to avoid this behavior from the Database side?

Comment: Does the application ever issue `or ('a' = 'a')` (causing the entire table to be returned)?

Comment: Occasionally, but it usually is chained to other conditions that limit the number of rows returned

Comment: May be [SPM](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28274/optplanmgmt.htm) can help in this case.

Comment: Yes, FTS is because of cursor_sharing set to FORCE, and it doesn't seem to be possible to avoid such behaviour(at least with 12C). Changing optimizer mode to `FIRST_ROWS(1)` gives better cost and execution time when condition in `OR ` ('a'='b'). evaluates to false, but it will be very inefficient when condition evaluates to true.  I'd consider using EXACT sharing mode (at least for that statement).  Also, in some cases even flushing shared pool periodically is better than `FORCE` cursor sharing mode.

Comment: Theoretically the predicate 'a' = 'b' (or 'a' = 'a' ) could be elimanated as tautology at early stage of the parsing. But it looks like the bind variable replacement (cursor sharing) takes place before. You can not do too much with that. Google the terms "bind variable peeking" and "SQL plan baseline". The most important rule for you is that a single sql_id (a sql statement hash) can have only one execution plan. The whole idea with the 'or' predicate is sick. You WANT full table scan if this predicate evaluates to true, while you want index access when it evalutates to false. IMHO the cursor

Comment: sharing was supposed to improve the performance. But now you face the negative impact of this "improvement". The best thing you can do is to contact the software vendor.

Answer (score 0):

You can not correct a bad implemented application from the database side in such a way that it will always work as expected. With cursor sharing the database tries to prevent parsing. This works when the application uses bind variables when working on item/person level and literals when working on group/class level.

You could try cursor_sharing force. This could correct some queries but at the same time hurt others.

You could try sql plan management but in my experience, when you really need it, it fails. Especially with literal littered applications. Sometimes you have luck but don't underestimate the amount of work you need to put in them. Auto sampling of plans is not the best idea here ....